# NetBeans doesn't recognize that dependency is a local project - how to fix?

Tags: maven, netbeans, java-8, dependency-management, netbeans-8

I have two pairs of projects that I develop in NetBeans, both of which have a GUI project, and a library project, where the GUI project depends on the library one.  In one of them, NetBeans recognizes that the dependency is local, and indicates as such with an Ma symbol, as seen below, with the dependency project in green:

[image: NetBeans showing that it recognizes the dependency is local]

This provides some nice functionality, most notably that the "Navigate to" (ctrl+click) functionality from the GUI project takes me to the source code in the library project.  I also don't have to manually rebuild the library project for the GUI project to pick up any changes.

However, for the other pair of projects, NetBeans will pick up that the dependency is in my local Maven repo, but does not recognize that the source code is a Maven project that it also has open:

[image: NetBeans not recognizing that a dependency is local]

I've tried looking through all the right-click menu options, removing and re-adding the dependency from the NetBeans GUI, comparing the pom.xml, comparing nb-actions.xml, and nb-configuration.xml, but cannot find any explanation of why one library is recognized as local, but the other is not.  The only information I've found online is at http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices, where it notes:

"*Hint: If you open a project that other projects depend on, the icon in other projects changes to a "maven project" icon to denote that the IDE knows about link between the projects. However such a link is only established when the groupId, artifactId and version all match in the dependency and project declaration. Frequently occurring problem is that you change an API signature in your library project, but the application is not picking up. Often it's caused by the fact that the application is using an older version of the library artifact. The artifact icon can help you track down these problems.*"

However, I've verified that the pom.xml of the GUI project depends on the version being built in the library project, and even made the versions identical between the GUI project and library, and the "maven project" icon still doesn't show up.

Does anyone know how to debug this issue, or if there's a magic setting somewhere that I'm missing for how to make this link work?  I've been trying with both NetBeans 8.2 and 8.1, and am compiling with Java 8 for both the successful pair of projects, and the unsuccessful ones.

Comment: How exactly did you add the "jimagereader" dependency in the second project? You could try to remove it from the pom and then re-add it from the "open projects". Click on the dependencies node of the project, choose "Add dependency" and then switch to the "Open Projects" tab on that and add the dependency through that. You might also want to try NetBeans 11.3

Comment: Initially it was via the pom, but when debugging this tonight, I attempted it as you described via the "Add dependency" -> "Open projects".  It didn't seem to make any difference.

I just downloaded 11.3, and observed the same behavior there.  Tested with both Java 8, and Java 14 for the GUI + Java 8 for the library (the library has some compatibility issues with Java 14).

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting the project a couple years later, I finally figured out a way to get the dependency to connect locally.

Change the artifact ID of the dependency, and update the dependent pom to match the new name.

This is admittedly bypassing the root issue rather than addressing it, but given the inability to pinpoint the root cause, seems the best option at this time.